# Run multiple net use commands for a process using c#

Tags: c#, process, windows-services

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
                                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C net use W: \\\\abcdpc25\\views\\Projects ";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

I want to run multiple net use commands and i am not sure how to go about it

I am not sure if something like below would work .

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/C net use W: \\\\abcdpc25\\views\\Projects 
                      net use H: \\\\abcdpc25\\views\\Project456 net use E: 
                      \\\\abcdpc25\\views\\Project123";
```

Comment: Don't do this, you cannot properly detect failure.  And this is *very* likely to fail.  Just call the [winapi function](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr/WNetAddConnection2.html) that does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use & as the separator between commands and it should work.

You can also put all the net use statements in a batch file and put the batch file name on your command line.

You can also launch multiple processes, one for each net use.

Comment: Currently i am using multiple processes using for loop. Will it be a right way to handle this or would using a batch file be more appropriate considering system performance and standards.

Comment: Depends on how frequently this gets called. If this is not done at a very high scale (e.g., per customer request), then I wouldn't worry about performance too much and just do what is simplest for you to code.